# Finding probabilities of jointly continuous random variables

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, solution-verification

**Question**

Suppose that random variables $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ have joint probability density function given by
$$f(y_1,y_2)=\begin{cases}cy_1^2y_2^2,\quad 0\leqslant y_1\leqslant y_2, y_1 + y_2\leqslant 2,\\0,\quad \text{elsewise}\end{cases}$$

a) Calculate the value of c.

b) What is the probability that $Y_1 + Y_2$ is less than $1$?

**My answers**

a)
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{2-y_2}\left(cy_1^2y_2^2\right)dy_1dy_2 &= \frac{16}{45}c \\ 
\implies \frac{16}{45}c & = 1 \\
c & =\frac{45}{16}
\end{aligned}$$

b)
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(Y_1 + Y_2 < 1) & = \mathbb{P}(Y_2 < 1 - Y_1)\\
& = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1-y_2}\left(\frac{45}{16} y_1^2y_2^2\right)dy_1dy_2 \\
& = \frac{1}{64}
\end{aligned}$$

However, I have just learnt joint PDFs and finding the limits of these double integrals are very confusing to me. May I know whether my approaches and answers to both parts are correct?

**Edit**

Following the comments, I have made some changes to my working and am wondering whether my answers are correct now.

a)
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{y_1}^{2-y_1}\left(cy_1^2y_2^2\right)dy_2dy_1 &= \frac{8}{45}c \\ 
\implies \frac{8}{45}c & = 1 \\
c & =\frac{45}{8}
\end{aligned}$$

b)
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(Y_1 + Y_2 < 1) & = \mathbb{P}(Y_2 < 1 - Y_1)\\
& = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{y_1}^{1-y_1}\left(\frac{45}{8} y_1^2y_2^2\right)dy_2dy_1 \\
& = \frac{1}{64}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: What you have done is correct.

Comment: The first calculation is not correct. The inequalities must be $0 \le y_1  \le y_2$ and $0 \le y_2 \le 2-y_1$. So the integral is $\int_0^1(\int_{y_1}^{2-y_1} (cy_1^2y_2^2)dy_2)dy_1$.

Comment: In the triangle  with vertexes $(0,0), (2,0), (0,2)$ defined by the second given inequality, the fist one is satisfied only in the triangle with vertexes $(0,0), (1,1), (2,0)$.

Comment: I always recommend drawing the support of $(Y_1,Y_2)$. This makes it much easier to get the limits of the integrals correct.

Comment: @kmitov Thank you for the pointer. Would my answer be correct now?

Comment: I think that now everything is correct.